# Filter Blood Pressure for Hypertension Categories, While Returning Higher Category

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2008.

I have a Blood_Pressure_Systolic field and a Blood_Pressure_Diastolic field. I need to use these two fields to identify normal blood pressure, prehypertension, stage 1 hypertension, and stage 2 hypertension based on the Mayo Clinic's categories here: [Mayo Clinic Blood Pressure Chart](http://www.mayoclinic.com/health/blood-pressure/HI00043)

I'm currently using the CASE expression below to filter the systolic ranges and the diastolic ranges for each category. However, if a person has a systolic blood pressure in a lower range and a diastolic blood pressure in a higher range, I want to return the higher range, and vice versa. For example, if John Smith has 125 systolic (prehypertension) and 95 diastolic (Stage 1 hypertension), then I want the field to return that he has Stage 1 hypertension.

```
CASE WHEN BP_Systolic < '120' AND BP_Diastolic < '80' THEN 'Normal'

WHEN BP_Systolic BETWEEN '120' AND '139' OR BP_Diastolic BETWEEN '80' AND '89' THEN 'Prehypertension'

WHEN BP_Systolic BETWEEN '140' AND '159' OR BP_Diastolic BETWEEN '90' AND '99' THEN 'Stage 1 Hypertension'

WHEN BP_Systolic >= '160' OR BP_Diastolic >= '100' THEN 'Stage 2 Hypertension'
END AS BP_Category
```

Comment: RDBMS? Looks like Oracle or mysql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that simply ordering the `CASE` clause would do it since it is parsed sequentially:

```
CASE 
    WHEN BP_Systolic >= '160' OR BP_Diastolic >= '100' THEN 'Stage 2 Hypertension'
    WHEN BP_Systolic BETWEEN '140' AND '159' OR BP_Diastolic BETWEEN '90' AND '99' THEN 'Stage 1 Hypertension'
    WHEN BP_Systolic BETWEEN '120' AND '139' OR BP_Diastolic BETWEEN '80' AND '89' THEN 'Prehypertension'
    WHEN BP_Systolic < '120' AND BP_Diastolic < '80' THEN 'Normal'
END AS BP_Category
```

Dummy fiddle to try it out: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8ad7f/3

Comment: I previously tried that and it returns "Stage 2 Hypertension" for every consumer.

Comment: are you sure the condition is good? it seems that the first when clause should be revised then... But maybe I'm wrong. EDIT: I'm reading your link and it seems correct. Please show an extract of the database to reflect the query results

Comment: also, I don't know how sql server handles conversions but are you sure the fields are strings and not numbers? (int)

Comment: Yes, the fields are varchar's. If I use AND between the systolic range and diastolic range for all categories then it works, but the last three categories use OR.

Comment: I'm sorry, I think there's a problem in your datas. Without an extract I can't help any further

Comment: Try CASTing - CAST(BP_Systolic as INT) >= 160 . I'd just remove that as a variable, because this should be working as Sebas says.

Comment: The original data is an integer but I converted it to varchar so I could label it with the stages of hypertension in my original table. I have changed it back to an integer for my CREATE TABLE and it appears to be more accurate when filtering in the new table, but I still found some errors. And there doesn't seem to be any pattern to the errors. It works when the systolic and diastolic fall within the same hypertension category. But when they're in different categories it sometimes defaults to the lower range and other times defaults to the higher range.

Comment: I tried this last night after changing it back to an integer and it didn't work; I tried it this morning and now it's working. I think I may have just had some problem connecting to the database or something. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

`case` statements are evaluated in order. So, this statement prioritizes "Normal" (although given its definition, the placement doesn't matter).  To prioritize something else, reverse the order:

```
CASE WHEN BP_Systolic >= '160' OR BP_Diastolic >= '100'
     THEN 'Stage 2 Hypertension'
     WHEN BP_Systolic BETWEEN '140' AND '159' OR
           BP_Diastolic BETWEEN '90' AND '99'
     THEN 'Stage 1 Hypertension'
     WHEN BP_Systolic BETWEEN '120' AND '139' OR
          BP_Diastolic BETWEEN '80' AND '89'
     THEN 'Prehypertension'
     WHEN BP_Systolic < '120' AND BP_Diastolic < '80'
     THEN 'Normal'
END AS BP_Category
```